# Active Model Serializer - How do I include an attribute conditionally? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, rest

I am using Active Model Serializers with my Rails 4 API, and I have been trying to figure out how to include the `auth_token` attribute in my JSON response *only* when the user logs in at `sessions#create`. I read the [AMS documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#attributes) and tried most of the seeming solutions but none worked.

Couple things to point out:

- `:auth_token` is not in the `UserSerializer`'s attributes list.
- Since the `auth_token` is controller-specific, I can't do the conditional logic in the `UserSerializer` unless there is a way to determine what controller was called in the Serializer. So no `def include_auth_token? ... end`.

Some of the things I've tried already:

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
        if user.active
          user.generate_auth_token   #=> Custom method
          user.save

          # Tried using the meta param
          render :json => user, :meta => {:auth_token => user.auth_token}

          # Tried using the include param both with 'auth_token' and 'user.auth_token'
          render :json => user, include: 'user.auth_token'
        end
    end
end
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to use something along the lines of `render :json => user, :include => :auth_token` to additionally include attributes not already defined in the `UserSerializer`.

What is the proper way to conditionally include attributes from the controller with AMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation, looks like the `include` will be available only in the v0.10.0 version. The correct docs from v0.9 are these: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.9.0#attributes.
I've used the `filter` method before, something like this should do the trick:

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  if user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
    if user.active
      user.generate_auth_token
      user.save

      render :json => user, :meta => {:auth_token => user.auth_token}
    end
  end
end



class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :auth_token

  def filter(keys)
   if meta && meta['auth_token']
     keys
   else
     keys - [:auth_token]
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the `render :json => user` call to serialize the user to a JSON payload, you can craft the payload yourself and have control over what is and what is not included.

```
user_payload = user.as_json

user_payload.merge!(:auth_token => user.auth_token) if include_auth_token?

render :json => user_payload
```

The `as_json` method Returns a hash representing the model. You can then modify this hash before the JSON serializer turns it into proper JSON.

Comment: This did work a bit, but not achieve my desired results. Using this method returned all attributes and using `:exclude` option in my `render :json` call (oddly) did not remove the attributes. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: If there is some weirdness in the `:exclude` option, you can always modify the hash directly in the last option like: `render :json => user_payload.except(:some, :keys, :to, :exclude)`

Answer (score 0):

You can define attributes conditionally. See [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md#attribute).